# Extending the YUI Panel

Tags: yui, panel

I have a requirement to extend the YUI Panel with some custom functionality that will be in a new file and shared across multiple views.

I am at a bit of a loss as to how best to go about this, can anyone give me any pointers please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to extend a Panel to create one that has a list in its body. I usually use `Y.Base.create` for this. It's a more declarative way of extending YUI classes than using a constructor and `Y.extend`. But I'll stay closer to your example in the YUI forums.

There are a couple of tricks dealing with WidgetStdMod (one of the components of `Y.Panel`), but mostly it's just about using `Y.extend` and following the YUI inheritance patterns. I'll try to answer with an example:

```
function MyPanel() {
    MyPanel.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}
// hack: call it the same so you get the same css class names
// this is good for demos and tests. probably not for real life
MyPanel.NAME = 'panel';

MyPanel.ATTRS = {
    listItems: {
        // YUI now clones this array, so all's right with the world
        value: []
    },
    bodyContent: {
        // we want this so that WidgetStdMod creates the body node
        // and we can insert our list inside it
        value: ''
    }
};

Y.extend(MyPanel, Y.Panel, {
    // always a nice idea to keep templates in the prototype
    LIST_TEMPLATE: '<ul class="yui3-panel-list"></ul>',

    initializer: function (config) {
        // you'll probably want to use progressive enhancement here
        this._listContainer = Y.Node.create(this.LIST_TEMPLATE);

        // initializer is also the place where you'll want to instantiate other
        // objects that will live inside the panel
    },

    renderUI: function () {
        // you're inheriting from Panel, so you'll want to keep its rendering logic
        // renderUI/bindUI/syncUI don't call the superclass automatically like
        // initializer and destructor
        MyPanel.superclass.renderUI.call(this);

        // Normally we would append stuff to the body in the renderUI method
        // Unfortunately, as of 3.5.0 YUI still removes all content from the body
        // during renderUI, so we either hack it or do everything in syncUI
        // Hacking WidgetStdModNode is doable but I don't have the code around
        // and I haven't memorized it
        //var body = this.getStdModNode('body');
    },

    syncUI: function () {
        // same here
        MyPanel.superclass.syncUI.call(this);

        // insert stuff in the body node
        var listContainer = this._listContainer.appendTo(this.getStdModNode('body'));

        Y.Array.each(this.get('listItems'), function (item) {
            listContainer.append('<li>' + item + '</li>');
        });
    }
});
```